# NEXT_LOCALE cookie is being ignored. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I need to manually set the user's locale and get access to it in `getStaticProps` for a multilingual static site.

I have 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to create a multilingual website without having language in the subpath or as a domain?
2. Why is `Next` reading my `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie wrong? I set the cookie to `me` and it says that locale is `en`. I get `me` as a locale only when I go to `localhost:3000/me`.

All I could find about the cookie is this sentence in the docs

> Next.js supports overriding the accept-language header with a NEXT_LOCALE=the-locale cookie. This cookie can be set using a language switcher and then when a user comes back to the site it will leverage the locale specified in the cookie.
>
> For example, if a user prefers the locale fr but a NEXT_LOCALE=en cookie is set the en locale will be used instead until the cookie is removed or expired.

Judging by this, the `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie should be read instead of subpath or from the domain, but in my case, the `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie is totally ignored.

Does this have something to do with `"next": "10.0.5"`. Do I need to downgrade?
Or could it be that I misunderstood something?

Comment: How are you setting the `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie? Can you see the cookie's value is the browser? Using the `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie will only override the [automatic locale detection](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#automatic-locale-detection), which is usually based on the `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: I discovered that it works on version 10.0.0 of NextJS and it doesn't work on anything above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Latest Next.js doesn't support it. I have raised a [PR](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/52112)
2. Try start your server with `nextConfig.i18n.localeDetection = true`. Set `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie and reload the page using root path `/`